# Multiple database connections in java web application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, multiple-databases

I want to design a web application (using java, spring, hibernate with mySQL). The data size is very big. So for every client I wish to create separate DB either on same server or on different nodes. 
I tried this using java, spring, hibernate with mySQL. But JVM takes huge memory and at times raises exception "out of heap space".

Is there any better way to manager multiple DB connections using above stack?

Comment: You need to add more specifics. Like what you tried how much memory it's already consuming? What servlet container? Do a jstack dump and jvisualvm and report back in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tomcat, you can increase the heap space just creating a environment variable  called JAVA_OPTS and specifying  the minimun (Xms) and maximun (Xmx) size for your heap: for example    JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"      (Note:there isn't any spaces between Xms and the size)

Comment: I already have set -Xms780m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxNewSize=780m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:CodeCacheMinimumFreeSpace=16m. I want the proper way of implementing multiple DB connections in spring and hibernate + mySQL.

Comment: @AnantNavagale you may need to set it higher, raising it to use the majority of the system's memory. In my experience it's best to use 64bit java going over 1024mb, or possibly you have a leak?

Comment: Be careful with the -XX:MaxPermSize, and probably MaxNewSize, since they get carved out of the heap. So, that 780 and 512 are taking big chunks away from your Xmx1025. I had a process that kept running out of heap even tho I had maxed it out, and the problem was that I had maxed out MaxPermSize as well, and lowering MaxPerm down to about 192 fixed the issue.  Try using jvisualvm to look at the memory usage of the process.  I find it very informative.

Answer (score 0):

You should use connection pools provided by your application server so they will help you to manage the DB connections in a better manner.

Comment: I have used DBCP connection pooling as suggested on apache site. I just the correct way of implementing multiple DB connections in spring and hibernate + mySQL